# AVAudioPlayer Memory Leak - Media Player Framework

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am using  AVAudioPlayer object to play an audio. I created an audioPlayer object  initially. I play an animation and when ever animation starts I play the audio and pause the audio when the animation is finished. I initially found three memory Leaks using Instruments. (The responsible caller mentioned was RegisterEmbedCodecs). After suggestion from a "ahmet emrah" in this forum to add MediaPlayer framework, the number of leaks reduced to one. And is there any way to completely get rid of it?

Thanks and regards,
krishnan.

Comment: After a long time searching in Google, I found this problem to occur only in iPhone Simulator and not in device. But while testing in device I was gifted with another memory leak name "CAPThreadStart". And the responsible library was the AudioToolbox. So if anyone has encountered the problem please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem resolved. This occured only in Simulator and not in the device.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post some code up.  This is typically how I play an audio file and I do not have any leaks appearing:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somefile" ofType:@"mp3"];  

AVAudioPlayer * newAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
self.theAudio = newAudio; // automatically retain audio and dealloc old file if new file is loaded

[newAudio release]; // release the audio safely

theAudio.delegate = self; 
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
[theAudio play];
```

Comment: Hi Friend,

I got this problem resolved. This occured only in Simulator and not in the device Thanks for your time.