# AVAudioPlayer not releasing memory with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios

I created a singleton with contains an AVAudioPlayer object

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface drwAudioPlayer : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property AVAudioPlayer *aPlayer;

+(drwAudioPlayer *) sharedPlayer {

    static drwAudioPlayer *sharedPlayer = nil;
    if (!sharedPlayer) {
        sharedPlayer = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }
    return sharedPlayer;
}

-(void) setPlayerEpisode:(NSData *) episodeFile {
    NSError *error;
    aPlayer = nil;
    aPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:episodeFile error:&error];
}
```

In my main view I included the above class and created an object of type drwAudioPlayer. When I call `[drwAudioPlayer.aPlayer setPlayerEpisode:foo]`, I see that the new file is getting loaded and the old one released.

But as soon as I start the playback of a file and then try to call `[drwAudioPlayer.aPlayer setPlayerEpisode:foo2]` the memory increases by the size of the new file being loaded.

What do I have to do to basically free up the memory before loading the new file to play.

I'm using ARC.

Comment: try self.aPlayer = nil instead, or use _aPlayer = nil, since you don't synthesize

Comment: My bad,I´m using synthesize in my code for aPlayer. Just copied it wrong. But I tried self.aPlayer but the result is the same. As soon as I´m starting playback, aPlayer never gets deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that there is an issue with iOS6 and also the simulator. So far I only tested my application in the simulator for leaking memory and not on an actual device. When running the code on an iPhone everything works like a charm and I have no leaking memory in my code.

I also found these posts on stackoverflow which are saying the same thing:

[Memory Leak AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840637/avaudioplayer-memory-leak-media-player-framework)

[Memory Leak iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553031/audiotoolbox-leak-in-ios6)

Answer (score -2):

A singleton is a memory leak, by definition. Do not use them. Instead, make a ref to the audio player in your code and when your view controller that uses the player goes away, the player will be deallocated. Under iOS, memory is not garbage collected, you simply cannot do things like this and expect the memory to get released, ARC is not a garbage collector.

Comment: I use a singleton because I want just want instance of the drwPlayer class that should manage the playback of all sounds in the application and is also responsible for saving playback positions. The mainview is a tableview. Behind each cell is an detailview which has its own file that can be played back. So when I switching views, I won´t to know if one file is still playing and then stop it and play the file fomr the actual view being displayed. That is the reason for the singleton.

Comment: Yes, I know that you think a singleton is a good approach. It is not. If the issue is access from one view controller to another, then you can always hang a property ref off your AppDelegate class. That way, you can set appDelegate.playerRef = nil and the normal property logic will handle the memory management. What you are doing is creating a global variable (a static ref in a module) and then setting it to an object, that defeats ARC and makes the code leak memory.

Comment: I think I get your point. But what I´m not understanding is, why the memory usage is goinf up as soon as I start the playback of the file.

Comment: I changed the code according to you @MoDJ suggestion. My detail view controller has now a protocol defined and I´m using the delegate mechanism to exchange the audio player between the different views and it works.But still I have the problem, that I´m loading a new file aPlayer = [AVAudioplayer alloc] initWithData...] the memory, which was used by the old file, which was playing before, is not getting freed up.

Comment: You will have to track the memory leak down, there are only so many places that could be holding a ref to the AVAudioPlayer. Be sure to check that any ref from a view controller uses "assign" to hold the delegate ref and not "retain". Use profile with the leaks tool and see if you can reproduce the issue on the actual device, if it only shows up in the simulator then it is likely not a real leak.